# How do I use a regex in my MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I want to search for a word+number if that SQL returns nothing, I will default it to a full `LIKE` search, is there any way to implement regex like this in SQL?

Example:

```
$queryWord = potato
```

- It should first search for potato+somenumber up to 4 digits
- It should return all matches with potato+somenumber
- If that fails, it defaults to a full search with wildcards on both sides

Like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `words` WHERE `searchWord` LIKE '$queryWord+number';";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {

    $sql =  "SELECT * FROM `words` WHERE `searchWord` LIKE '%$queryWord%';"; // full search
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    // etc etc

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change your query to this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `words` WHERE `searchWord` REGEXP '$queryWord(\d{1,4})';";
```

and here is a [Rubular that proves the Regex](http://rubular.com/r/Kc5CnpjbPB).

Comment: Just to say, there are 2 keywords that can be used in MySQL for regular expression matching: `REGEXP` and `RLIKE`, they are the same.